# Akka Actor - Receive Pattern Match by Generic Type

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka, actor

I have a generic actor class and I want to pattern match with the generic type in the receive method.

For example:

```
class Test[S] extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _: S => println("yes")
    case _ => println("no")
  }
}

val ac = system.actorOf(Props(new Test[Int]))
ac ! "abc" // expect print "no" 
ac ! 3     // expect print "yes"
```

However, it seems it never goes to the second case, and always printout "yes"...

How can I make it print "no"?

Comment: my bad... fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem

You've just stumbled upon a thing called *type erasure*. It means, that  generic type information is removed during compilation (JVM has no idea about generics). So in runtime, your actor will look like this:

```
class Test extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _: Object => println("yes")
    case _ => println("no")
  }
}
```

That's why `ac ! "abc"` as well as `ac ! 3` will always be matched against the first case.

Fortunately, Scala provides mechanisms, that help overcome this problem. You can read more about them [in this article](https://medium.com/@sinisalouc/overcoming-type-erasure-in-scala-8f2422070d20) and [in the docs](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html).

## Solution

tldr; You can find a working example [here, on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/yncCdv77RAqJQSG1g3YYrA).

You should use one of those mechanisms: a *ClassTag*. You can **think of it** as an object, that holds all the information available at compile time in the runtime.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object Main extends App {

  class Test[S](implicit ct: ClassTag[S]) extends Actor {
    override def receive: Receive = {
      case _: S => println("yes")
      case _ => println("no")
    }
  }

  val system = ActorSystem()

  val ac = system.actorOf(Props(new Test[Int]))
  ac ! "abc" // expect print "no"
  ac ! 3 // expect print "yes"

  system.terminate()

}
```

You may wonder where can we find an implicit instance of ClassTag[T]. Fortunately, the compiler will provide one on demand.

Bonus: You can rewrite `class Test[S](implicit ct: ClassTag[S]) extends Actor` to use so-called [*Context Bounds*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds.html): `class Test[S: ClassTag] extends Actor`.

You can read this signature as follows:

> *A class Test is parametrized by type S, for which there is available ClassTag[S] in an implicit scope*.

Comment: Thanks so much for providing working example and lots of resources :) I didn't know about Scastie. It's cool!

Comment: Btw, is there type tag for `trait` too?

Comment: For example, if it's `trait Test[S]`??

Comment: You're welcome :)! If the actor was trait, you can obtain a ClassTag in a different way by calling _classTag_ method: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/tVa9ENThQlydtetmpS0iGg